# Will a 5 year Irish ban keep me from getting a UK visa?

Tags: uk, ireland, visa-bans

I had a 5 year ban from the Republic of Ireland because I used a fake job offer letter and fake work permit that the agent gave me to submit.

Now I have a certificate of sponsorship (COS) to work as a health care assistant in the UK, but a friend told me that it will be impossible to get a visa because of the Irish ban. I have not started applying for the visa, but I hope to tell them the truth. What chance do I have?

Comment: You *had* a 5-year ban.  Do you mean the ban has expired?

Comment: Ban is still on

Answer (score 10):

The only way to know for certain if you will receive a visa or not is to apply for one and see if you are accepted or rejected.

In your specific case, with a rejection for deception from a country that [shares information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area) with the country you intend to travel to, your odds of success are probably not good.

Note, however, that a way to make your odds even worse would be to attempt to conceal your Irish refusal from the UK authorities; they will quite likely be able to find out anyway, and then you will be seen as attempting to deceive the UK as well, which is not a good position to be in.

Comment: Should OP volunteer with the information, *BTW, I lied to your Irish friends and I'm sorry, but this time I'm not lying, pinky swear*?  Is the information on visa denials due to deception stored indefinitely, or does it expire at some point?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to volunteer, but if asked the answer should be truthful and with minimal information. For example, if the question is "Have you ever been refused entry by [description of countries that include Ireland]?" the answer should be "Yes". If asked for details they should provide just enough true details to reply to the answer, no more.

Comment: @gerrit Information is probably stored (practically) indefinitely. Whether or not the officials will take it into account is not exactly defined in the law, it's always at their discretion. I'd say the chances of getting a UK visa while the Irish ban is in force are slim. Afterwards, it should be okay-ish.